# Bootstrap 4 Popover with HTML Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This is my code, but it will not work.

When I use the native Bootstrap PopOver with HTML in it's content, the frontend is not displaying that PopOver and the HTML Source is malformatted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
        <style>
            .popover{
                color: #757575 !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
             <span href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-html="true" data-content="<div class="popover">text text</div>">Toggle popover</span>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Remove Class property.
It can work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
        <style>
            .popover{
                color: #757575 !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <span href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-html="true" data-content="<div>text text</div>">Toggle popover</span>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to display HTML inside a bootstrap popover, but somehow it's not working. I found some answers here but it won't work for me. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just wrap the `popover` class in single quotes like this.

```
<div class='popover'>text text</div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="popover">text text</div>
```

Answer (score 33):

Remember to set `data-html="true"` (along with the other `data-` attributes) on the popover element. Otherwise HTML content won't be rendered correctly.

More details can be found in the docs for Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/popovers/#options

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

```
$element.popover({
    animation: false,
    html: true,
    sanitize: false,
    placement: 'bottom',
    trigger: 'manual',
    content: '<button type="button" id="button-image" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="mdi mdi-edit"></i></button> <button type="button" id="button-clear" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="mdi mdi-trash-can-outline"></i></button>',
});
```

Comment: You should always explain your answer. Thanks.

Comment: `sanitize` key is what made my html appear. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding `data-html="true"` to all popovers, you can just use it like this:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html:true});
```